# Is this the simplest way to visually prove the "scalene trapezoid area formula"

Tags: area

Please refer to image.  Is there a simpler way to visually prove the scalene trapezoid area formula?

[image: Scalene trapezoid area proof]

Comment: The way I was taught at school was by prolonging each base by a segment of the same length as the other one (in the same half plane with respect to some side), and then remark that the resulting figure was a parallelogram with base $(a+b)$, height $h$ and double the area.

Comment: Thanks Saucy.  Looks like Hagen von Eitzen has visualised this for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a rotated copy of your trapezoid to form a parallelogram of twice the area.

[image]

---

In case you forgot that this parallelogram has area $(a+b)h$, note that the triangles in the following image are congruent, hence the area of the parallelogram equals that of the rectangle.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Hagen.  That is a lot simpler.